# How can I get this switch statement to work using a scanner?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, java.util.scanner, phonetics

I'm trying to write a program that will switch any letter of the alphabet (upper or lower cases) into the Phontic alphabet. For example, If I enter "A" or "a" my program will give me (change it to) "Alpha".
I've done so much research on this and switch statements but I keep getting stuck. I've realized that I can't use 'char' in a scanner. However, when I change 'char' into a 'String' my switch statement messes up (specifically the *toUpperCase* in my code gets underlined. I can't see my mistake. Here's what I've done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhoneticTranslate {
public static void main(String[] args) {


char letter;
String phonetic;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Please enter a letter: ");
letter = kb.next();

switch(Character.toUpperCase(letter))
{
case 'A':
    phonetic = "Alpha";
break;
case 'B':
    phonetic = "Bravo";
    break;
case 'C':
    phonetic = "Charlie";
    break;
case 'D': 
    phonetic = "Delta";
    break;
case 'E':
    phonetic = "Echo";
    break;
case 'F':
    phonetic = "Foxtrot";
    break;
case 'G':
    phonetic = "Golf";
    break;
case 'H':
    phonetic = "Hotel";
    break;
case 'I':
    phonetic = "India";
    break;
case 'J':
    phonetic = "Juliet";
case 'K':
    phonetic = "Kilo";
    break;
case 'L':
    phonetic = "Lima";
    break;
case 'M':
    phonetic = "Mike";
    break;
case 'N':
    phonetic = "November";
    break;
case 'O':
    phonetic = "Oscar";
    break;
case 'P':
    phonetic = "Papa";
    break;
case 'Q':
    phonetic = "Quebec";
    break;
case 'R':
    phonetic = "Romeo";
    break;
case 'S':
    phonetic = "Sierra";
    break;
case 'T':
    phonetic = "Tango";
    break;
case 'U':
    phonetic = "Uniform";
    break;
case 'V':
    phonetic = "Victor";
    break;
case 'W':
    phonetic = "Whiskey";
    break;
case 'X':
    phonetic = "X-Ray";
    break;
case 'Y':
    phonetic = "Yankee";
    break;
case 'Z':
    phonetic = "Zulu";
    break;


}

}
}
```

Comment: I would rather maintain a Map<Character, String> to store the `phonetic` for each character..

Answer (score 6):

You need to use charAt. `Scanner.next()` method returns `String` not `char` so you will need to convert `String` to `char`

```
letter = kb.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: you are fast, I was just writing the same =)

Answer (score 3):

You can better create a `Map<Character, String>` to save yourself from writing `26 cases` in switch. This way you just have to `get` the String for a particular character.

```
Map<Character, String> mapping = new HashMap<Character, String>();
mapping.put('a', "Alpha");
mapping.put('b', "Beta");
..  And so on..
```

Of course you have to take the burden of initializing the `Map`, but it will be better than a `Mess` of `switch - case`

Benefit is that, you can also `populate` the `Map` from some `file` later on.

Then when you read character from scanner, use `charAt(0)` to fetch the first character, because `Scanner.next()` returns a String: -

```
letter = kb.next().charAt(0);

// Fetch the Phonetic for this character from `Map`
phonetic = mapping.get(letter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String letter;
String phonetic;
Map<String,String> codes = new HashMap<String,String>();
codes.put("A","Alpha");
codes.put("B","Bravo");
codes.put("C","Charlie");
codes.put("D","Delta");
    // not showing all assignments to make it shorter
codes.put("W","Whiskey");
codes.put("X","X-Ray");
codes.put("Y","Yankee");
codes.put("Z","Zulu");

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a letter: ");
letter = kb.next().toUpperCase();

phonetic = codes.get(letter);

if (phonetic == null) {
    System.out.println("bad code : " + letter);
} else {
    System.out.println("Phonetic: " + phonetic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Scanner.next()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) returns a `String`, not a `char`, so you need to get the first character of that `String` using [`String.charAt(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) before comparing it to `char`s.