# How can I get this switch statement to recognize integers?

Tags: java, int, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a program that will switch any letter  of the alphabet (upper or lower cases) **AND number** into the Phonetic alphabet. For example, if I enter "A" or "a" my program will give me (change it to) "Alpha". Moreover, if I enter "1" it will return "One". I've successfully managed to  work the 'enter-any-letter' aspect of it, but my program does not recognize numbers. I tried putting **int** but my Scanner does not recognize this. I put a **default** in my code but still...no prevail. Should I use an if statement instead?

Further note:
This is question is a continuation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938563/how-can-i-get-this-switch-statement-to-work-using-a-scanner)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhoneticTranslate {
public static void main(String[] args) {

 int number = 0;
char letter;
String phonetic = null;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Please enter a letter or number: ");
letter = kb.next().charAt(0);

switch(Character.toUpperCase(letter))
{
case 'A':
    phonetic = "Alpha"; 
break;
case 'B':
    phonetic = "Bravo";
    break;
// ... rest of cases for letters
case 'Z':
    phonetic = "Zulu";
    break;
    default:

            Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
            number = kb.nextInt();

            switch(number)
            {
            case '1':
                phonetic = "One";
                break;
            case '2':
                phonetic = "Two";
                break;
                            // ... rest of cases for numbers
            case '8':
                phonetic = "Eight";
                break;
            case '9':
                phonetic = "Nine";
                break;
            }

}
            System.out.println("You Entered " +  letter + ". This letter indicates: " + phonetic);
            System.out.println("You Entered" + number + ". This number indicates: " + phonetic);


}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A **giant switch/case clause** is a code smell, try this:

Add every key/value pair into a Map, then you retrieve the values with `get`. No switch/case needed.

```
String letter;
String phonetic;
Map<String,String> codes = new HashMap<String,String>();
codes.put("A","Alpha");
codes.put("B","Bravo");
codes.put("C","Charlie");
codes.put("D","Delta");
    // not showing all "puts" to make it shorter
codes.put("W","Whiskey");
codes.put("X","X-Ray");
codes.put("Y","Yankee");
codes.put("Z","Zulu");
codes.put("0","Zero");
codes.put("1","One");
    // not showing all "puts" to make it shorter
codes.put("9","Nine");    

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a letter: ");
letter = kb.next().toUpperCase(); // convert key to uppercase

phonetic = codes.get(letter);  // search the value in the map using the key

if (phonetic == null) {
    System.out.println("bad code : " + letter);
} else {
    System.out.println("Phonetic: " + phonetic);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have written your cases over characters: -

```
case '1': // This is checking for character '1'
```

You need to change your cases to take `integer` values: -

```
switch(number) {
    case 1:
           phonetic = "One";
           break;
    case 2:
        ... so on
```

Comment: @Rohit Jain This is great! I've done that and it works but when I input an integer number, I have to type it in twice. I think it has something to do with the fact that there are two Scanners. Is there a way so that I don't have to enter a number twice??

Comment: @user1753668. Well I would say, you shouldn't have a different switch case for integers. Continue with your previous scanner, and test with '1', '2', so on.. That will be a better way to do..

Comment: @user1753668 But let me see why you are having your current problem.

Comment: @user1753668 There you go.. You have defined a scanner variable `x`, but are using `kb` -> `number = kb.nextInt();`.. Change it to: - `number = x.nextInt();` Before your switch-case for integers starts.

Comment: @RohitJain I didn't realize the OP was calling `nextInt()`, this sound like the right answer in this case

Answer (score 0):

Either don't include the quotes around the number (" case 1: phonetic = "One"" etc), or continue using the char value. I think either one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement is checking for the unicode char representation of integers.  By this specification, `'1'` is the character "1" which translates to the integer 49.

Put the int representation of each value in the switch statement:

```
switch (number) {
    case 1:
        phonetic = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = x.nextInt();
    String phonetic = null;
    switch(number)
    {
    case 1:
        phonetic = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
        phonetic = "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        phonetic = "Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        phonetic = "Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        phonetic = "Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        phonetic = "Six";
        break;
    case 7:
        phonetic = "Seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        phonetic = "Eight";
        break;
    case 9:
        phonetic = "Nine";
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASCII codes for the numbers instead , that's what chars are anyway. But why do you need to do it? Doesnt your code already work?

Answer (score 0):

Continue your cases into the characters representing integers:

```
case 'Z':
    phonetic = "Zulu";
    break;
case '1':
    phonetic = "One";
    break;
case '2':
    // ...
```

This will work, so long as you only want to handle single-digit numbers.

This matches your problem description, though keeping both a `letter` and `number` variable and printing them out separately suggests some additional functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the input value is a digit(int). If not return

```
while(true){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int number=0;    
try{
    int number = x.nextInt();
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    continue;
    }
    String phonetic = null;
    switch(number)
    {
    case 1:
        phonetic = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
        phonetic = "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        phonetic = "Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        phonetic = "Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        phonetic = "Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        phonetic = "Six";
        break;
    case 7:
        phonetic = "Seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        phonetic = "Eight";
        break;
    case 9:
        phonetic = "Nine";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one sir

```
package phone;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneticTranslate {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int number = 0;
  char letter;
  String phonetic = null;

  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


  System.out.print("Please enter a letter or number: ");
  letter = kb.next().charAt(0);

  switch (Character.toUpperCase(letter)) {
   case 'A':
    phonetic = "Alpha";
    break;
   case 'B':
    phonetic = "Bravo";
    break;
    // ... rest of cases for letters
   case 'Z':
    phonetic = "Zulu";
    break;
   default:

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    number = kb.nextInt();

    switch (number) {
     case 1:
      phonetic = "One";
      break;
     case 2:
      phonetic = "Two";
      break;
      // ... rest of cases for numbers
     case 8:
      phonetic = "Eight";
      break;
     case 9:
      phonetic = "Nine";
      break;
    }

  }
  System.out.println("You Entered " + letter + ". This letter indicates: " + phonetic);
  System.out.println("You Entered" + number + ". This number indicates: " + phonetic);


 }

}
```